# Visual Studio solution doesn't load after running CMake without errors

Tags: azerothcore

On Windows. CMake looks like it completed successfully and I could click Open Project, but Visual Studio couldn't load the solution.

Output from opening the project in Visual Studio 2019:

C:\ACBuild\deps\zlib\zlib.vcxproj : error  : The application for the project is not installed.

Is zlib a dependency I missed?

Answer (score 0):

So, I clicked "Open Project" and it worked the second time. Not sure what happened. Maybe some background process wasn't completed the first time.